# Debugger doesn't stop at break points (Arquillian, TomEE, OpenJPA Enhancer, Maven, JUnit, and IntelliJ)

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, junit, openjpa, apache-tomee

I'm writing a web app that uses JAX-RS (Apache CXF) and JPA (Apache OpenJPA) and is deployed using TomEE+. I've started using Arquillian via the arquillian-tomee-embedded maven dependency to unit test my REST services.

When I use IntelliJ to launch the test phase of Maven's build lifecycle everything works great. It runs OpenJPA's enhancer on my JPA Entities, kicks off the unit tests, and I'm able to successfully call my web services and they're able to successfully access the database.

Unfortunately, if I launch the test phase in debug mode everything still works but none of my breakpoints hit. What must I do to correct this problem?

I've found a tedious workaround. I can right click each unit test and run in debug mode and the debugger will hit breakpoints...but I have to manually run the OpenJPA enhancer beforehand in order for the JPA code to work.

Comment: whaddaya mean by "launch the test phase in debug mode "? what is the command line of maven? if you mean "-X", then it means that Maven runs in debug mode, not that it debugs your app.

Comment: I'm not using Maven via command line. I'm using Maven through IntelliJ IDEA. I right click the test phase of the maven life cycle and I click the Debug menu item.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you "launch the test phase in debug mode ", it means that **Maven runs in debug mode**, not that it debugs your app. You cannot debug your app through maven. Maven runs the tests using surefire-plugin, and you cannot use breakpoints and debug.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I just started using IntelliJ and Maven. To fix my issue I used IntelliJ to create a JUnit Run/Debug Configuration and added the openjpa:enhance goal to the "Before launch" list. Now I can run my tests without the tedious manual process I described earlier. Thanks!

Comment: @EdLaFave man, you just saved my sanity! I'm using Idea 14 CE, I could see that starting Maven 'test' in debug had connected to the VM/socket, but NO breakpoint action!!! I created a JUnit config, as you recommend, doing a Maven 'compile' beforehand, that worked, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There can be two possibilities:
1) The code / break-point(s) are not reachable / not getting called with current context.
2) You are NOT running application in Debug mode.

Make sure that you are Debugging the application and not run it like "Run As..."

Considering that you are using Eclipse, Run -> Debug As -> <-Your Target Application->

Also make sure that where ever you have added breakpoints, those lines are reachable.

Comment: I've got a breakpoint on the first line of the unit test and it hits when I use the workaround I described so I'm not worried about reach-ability. I'm also sure that when I launch the Maven test phase it is done so using debug mode. I launch it using the debug icon in the upper right hand of IntelliJ and it launches the Debug window.

Comment: Ok. And what is that line.

Comment: Hey, then please add log / print statement and add breakpoint to that,
then you'll know whether your test case is being executed or not.

Answer (score 0):

I've hit problems with IntelliJ debugging not hitting breakpoints before. You may have luck disabling the JUnit plugin and restarting IDEA.